# javascript clonenode() method is not working with safari

Tags: javascript

My code is perfectly working with IE but its not working with safari.Clonenode() method is not working in safari .
I have a code like this

```
function ApplyNowWizard_addVehicleTypeList(vehicleDOM) 
{
        oParent = $(this.data).get(0);
        oParent.documentElement.appendChild(vehicleDOM.cloneNode(true).documentElement);
 }
```

In safari vehicleDOM.cloneNode(true).documentElement give null.

Comment: What is `vehicleDOM` and what is the result of `vehicleDOM.cloneNode(true)` in Safari?

Comment: VehicleDOM is xml DOM Node and result of vehicleDOM.cloneNode(true) is null

Answer (score 2):

As `documentElement` is a `Document` field, I assume `vehicleDOM` must be a `Document`. Note the DOM specification comment about [`cloneNode`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-3A0ED0A4):

> And, cloning `Document`, `DocumentType`, `Entity`, and `Notation` nodes is implementation dependent.

Since what you really want is a clone of the document element *anyway*, it sounds like you may be better off cloning that rather than the `Document`:

```
oParent.documentElement.appendChild(vehicleDOM.documentElement.cloneNode(true));
```