# cloneNode() JS call not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, clonenode

I am using cloneNode() it's working fine in IE but it's not working in Safari.

```
function ApplyNowWizard_addVehicleTypeList(vehicleDOM) 
{
   oParent = $(this.data).get(0);
   oParent.documentElement.appendChild(vehicleDOM.cloneNode(true).documentElement);
}
```

where `vehicleDom` type is `IXMLDOMDocument2`.

vehicleDOM.cloneNode(true) giving `null` in safari.

Comment: An [interesting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14933092/1169519) question? Maybe a dup, even an exact dup?

Comment: @Teemu nice search but that was asked by one my colleague, and answers provided there were not working that's why i asked it again

Comment: That's what I thought (hope not a "double user"), but this question is still a duplicate : (.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link, I think possibly this is the solution

http://jsdom.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/appendchild-problem-in-google-chrome-and-safari/

Also note

Opera and Safari cannot clone Document or DocumentType nodes (Opera throws a DOMException (code 9: NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR), where Safari creates a null object); Firefox and Internet Explorer can clone these types of nodes (where they're available in the first place).

Ref: http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/cloneNode